Why is my validation accuracy worse than train accuracy?
I am training ResNet50 on Chestxray dataset. My training data is around 15000 Samples, 1500 in validation and 3000 in testing. It is multilabel classification problem and I have 13 labels and I have one hot encoded it. I'm encountering an issue while training. Despite observing an improvement in training accuracy over epochs, the validation accuracy seems to degrade. I've tried several experiments (manipulate learning rate, changing architecture) and troubleshooting steps but haven't been able to resolve this issue. I have used a lot of data augmentations too but it is not converging. What should I do to sort it ?
Architecture
learning_rate = 0.001
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
adam_optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)

resnet50 = ResNet50(input_shape=(256, 256, 3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

for layer in resnet50.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

x = Flatten()(resnet50.output)
prediction = Dense(13, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inputs=resnet50.input, outputs=prediction)

model.compile(optimizer=adam_optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=val_dataset,
    callbacks=[early_stopping]

Results
Epoch 1/100
477/477 [==============================] - 44s 83ms/step - loss: 1.2993 - accuracy: 0.1122 - val_loss: 1.0983 - val_accuracy: 0.1010

Epoch 2/100
477/477 [==============================] - 38s 80ms/step - loss: 1.0298 - accuracy: 0.1843 - val_loss: 1.3670 - val_accuracy: 0.0976

Epoch 3/100
477/477 [==============================] - 39s 81ms/step - loss: 0.9871 - accuracy: 0.2328 - val_loss: 1.1190 - val_accuracy: 0.1155

Epoch 4/100
477/477 [==============================] - 39s 81ms/step - loss: 0.9146 - accuracy: 0.2757 - val_loss: 1.2730 - val_accuracy: 0.0797

Epoch 5/100
477/477 [==============================] - 38s 81ms/step - loss: 0.9076 - accuracy: 0.3011 - val_loss: 1.4535 - val_accuracy: 0.0708

Epoch 6/100
477/477 [==============================] - 39s 82ms/step - loss: 0.9280 - accuracy: 0.3104 - val_loss: 1.6235 - val_accuracy: 0.0632

Epoch 7/100
477/477 [==============================] - 39s 81ms/step - loss: 0.8828 - accuracy: 0.3356 - val_loss: 1.3770 - val_accuracy: 0.0777

Epoch 8/100
477/477 [==============================] - 39s 82ms/step - loss: 0.8223 - accuracy: 0.3633 - val_loss: 1.3722 - val_accuracy: 0.1512

Epoch 9/100
477/477 [==============================] - 39s 81ms/step - loss: 0.8407 - accuracy: 0.3669 - val_loss: 1.3479 - val_accuracy: 0.1856

Epoch 10/100
477/477 [==============================] - 39s 81ms/step - loss: 0.8931 - accuracy: 0.3773 - val_loss: 1.6562 - val_accuracy: 0.0784

Epoch 11/100
477/477 [==============================] - 39s 81ms/step - loss: 0.9010 - accuracy: 0.3832 - val_loss: 1.9345 - val_accuracy: 0.0804

Epoch 12/100
477/477 [==============================] - 39s 81ms/step - loss: 0.8932 - accuracy: 0.3961 - val_loss: 1.8141 - val_accuracy: 0.0900

Epoch 13/100
477/477 [==============================] - 39s 81ms/step - loss: 0.8961 - accuracy: 0.4017 - val_loss: 2.1651 - val_accuracy: 0.0598

Epoch 14/100
477/477 [==============================] - 39s 82ms/step - loss: 0.7799 - accuracy: 0.4318 - val_loss: 1.8136 - val_accuracy: 0.0997


This phenomenon is known as overfitting. Although various countermeasures have been proposed, it is impossible to determine what will be effective based solely on the information you provided. The only thing that can be said is that there is no silver bullet for this problem.

@ken, Should i provide you my pre-processing stuff, may be that can help you if I am doing something wrong ?.
